# How to go back to slide 1 when restart button click using Slick.JS

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I am having trouble adding restart function using slick.js. What I want to happen is that when the slider reaches the last slide there's a button saying start again and when the user clicks the button the slider will go to slide 1 but I did not use `` loop: false ```.

Here's the full code: https://codepen.io/tezahzulueta-the-looper/pen/WNvpZoV

```js
$(function () {
  $('.timeline-nav').slick({
    slidesToShow: 28,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.timeline-slider',
    centerMode: false,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    mobileFirst: true,
    arrows: false,
    infinite: false,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 4,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 0,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 4,
          slidesToScroll: 2,
        }
      }
    ]
  });

  $('.timeline-slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    asNavFor: '.timeline-nav',
    centerMode: true,
    cssEase: 'ease',
    edgeFriction: 0.5,
    mobileFirst: true,
    speed: 500,
    infinite: false,
    arrows: true,
    prevArrow: $('.prev'),
    nextArrow: $('.next'),
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 0,
        settings: {
          centerMode: false
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          centerMode: true
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  
  $('.timeline-slider').slick('slickGoTo', 0);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Solve this by adding restart function see below:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.timeline-nav').slick({
    slidesToShow: 28,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.timeline-slider',
    centerMode: false,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    mobileFirst: true,
    arrows: false,
    infinite: false,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 4,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 0,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 4,
          slidesToScroll: 2,
        }
      }
    ]
  });

  $('.timeline-slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    asNavFor: '.timeline-nav',
    centerMode: true,
    cssEase: 'ease',
    edgeFriction: 0.5,
    mobileFirst: true,
    speed: 500,
    arrows: true,
    prevArrow: $('.prev'),
    nextArrow: $('.next'),
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 0,
        settings: {
          centerMode: false
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          centerMode: true
        }
      }
    ]
  });

});

function restart() {
  $('.timeline-slider').slick('slickGoTo', 0);
}
```